# Как переместить регистр 64-бит в 8-бит fasm

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Я сейчас пишу свой первый компилятор(до этого писал только интерпретаторы) на питоне. И до этого я не работал с ассемблером, решил сделать с помощью fasm.

И я хочу записать 8-бит в память, и это число я достаю с стека с помощью `pop` и в стеке числа должны быть 64-битовые. Но для того, что бы записать 8-бит как я понял мне нужен регистр на 8-бит, как мне из стека достать число и перевести его в 8-бит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сейчас решил посмотреть в похожий компилятор и нашёл вариант, который работает, но я не полностью понимаю почему, как я понимаю эти регистры как то связаны, но чтение и запись выглядит так.

```
pop rax
pop rbx
mov [mem+rax], bl
```

```
pop rax
xor rbx, rbx
mov bl, [mem+rax]
push rbx
```

Comment: `bx == bh << 8 | bl` , `ebx == 0<<16 | bx` , `rbx == 0<<32 | ebx` [Регистр процессора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регистр_процессора) то-есть `bh` - это ссылка на биты большей половины. если поменять 'bh', то значение `bx` изменится.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте подходящий вариант команды `MOVZX`

Comment: movzx делает противоположную операцию - расширяет более узкий операнд в более широкий с дополнением нулями.

Comment: Вы можете сохранить младщую 8-битную часть любого регистра AL/BL/CL/DL

Comment: Логично. Но не понятно каким боком к вопросу ваш ответ с MOVZX.

Comment: Потому что все мы ошибаемся и я не исключение. Я неразобрался в чем ваш вопрос.